# Why are my columns getting repeated when I call the function a second time?

Tags: r

I am using this function to create n-day accumulations of a time series.

```
masterfunction <-function(df,accum_var,accum_days){
  df<-cbind(df,rollapply(df[[accum_var]], accum_days, sum, fill=NA, align='right'))
}
odd<-masterfunction(df=odd,accum_var = "PRECIP",accum_days = 4)
odd<-masterfunction(df=odd,accum_var = "OBS_Q",accum_days = 2)
```

But when I run it the second time (for OBS_Q), the first column (for PRECIP) gets repeated instead. Any pointers how I can fix this? Also, any suggestions if I can improve this code where I can give the function a list of variables (accum_var) instead of calling it again and again?

```
    odd<-structure(list(DATE = 19630101:19630106, PRECIP = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.04), OBS_Q = c(1.61, 1.48, 1.4, 1.33, 1.28, 1.27), swb = c(1.75, 
1.73, 1.7, 1.67, 1.65, 1.63), gr4j = c(1.9, 1.77, 1.67, 1.58, 
1.51, 1.44), isba = c(0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83, 0.83), noah = c(1.31, 
1.19, 1.24, 1.31, 1.44, 1.55), sac = c(1.99, 1.8, 1.66, 1.57, 
1.46, 1.41), swap = c(1.1, 1.05, 1.08, 0.99, 0.88, 0.83), vic.mm.day. = c(2.1, 
1.75, 1.55, 1.43, 1.32, 1.17)), .Names = c("DATE", "PRECIP", 
"OBS_Q", "swb", "gr4j", "isba", "noah", "sac", "swap", "vic.mm.day."
), row.names = 366:371, class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Your function adds a column (`n` day sum) to `odd` every time it is executed. Is this expected behavior? Since you want to run "again and again", are you sure you want to append an extra column instead of replacing an existing one?

Comment: 1. Yes, expected behavior. 2. Yes, append it. I am a newbie, so I'm sure this is not the best way to achieve it. Ideally, I would like to pass a list of "accum_var" and the function would automatically create one column for each accum_var. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

New function that performs the same operation as your `masterfunction`

```
masterfunction2 <-function(accum_var, df = odd, suffix = "_new") {
  j <- data.frame(rollapply(data = df[, accum_var[1]],
                            width = as.numeric(accum_var[2]),
                            FUN = sum, fill=NA,
                            align='right'))
  names(j) = paste0(accum_var[1], suffix)
  return(j) }
```

Use a list as  your input, your column name followed by `width` parameter

```
i = list(c("PRECIP", 4),
         c("PRECIP", 2), 
         c("OBS_Q", 2), 
         c("noah", 3))
```

Get the output. Use `suffix` to change your new column names. `df` to change your data.table name.

```
cbind(odd, do.call(cbind, sapply(X = i, FUN = masterfunction2, df = odd, suffix = "_roll")))

        DATE PRECIP OBS_Q  swb gr4j isba noah  sac swap vic.mm.day. PRECIP_roll OBS_Q_roll noah_roll
366 19630101   0.00  1.61 1.75 1.90 0.83 1.31 1.99 1.10        2.10          NA         NA        NA
367 19630102   0.00  1.48 1.73 1.77 0.83 1.19 1.80 1.05        1.75          NA       3.09        NA
368 19630103   0.00  1.40 1.70 1.67 0.83 1.24 1.66 1.08        1.55          NA       2.88      3.74
369 19630104   0.00  1.33 1.67 1.58 0.83 1.31 1.57 0.99        1.43        0.00       2.73      3.74
370 19630105   0.00  1.28 1.65 1.51 0.83 1.44 1.46 0.88        1.32        0.00       2.61      3.99
371 19630106   0.04  1.27 1.63 1.44 0.83 1.55 1.41 0.83        1.17        0.04       2.55      4.30
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I learnt many things from this. Just a few quick questions: 1. I am getting this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , accum_var[1], with = F) : 
  unused argument (with = F). ......... 2. How can I adapt this to use the same variable multiple times? Example:  i = list(c("PRECIP", 4),c("PRECIP", 2)
         c("OBS_Q", 2),
         c("noah", 3))

Comment: Shouldn't your `odd` be class data.table? `with` is an optional keyword for `data.table`. What does your `class(odd)` output? You are missing a comma: `i = list(c("PRECIP", 4),c("PRECIP", 2), c("OBS_Q", 2), c("noah", 3))`.

Comment: Hi, my class(odd) = data.frame. Should I convert it to data.table?

Comment: In the code snippet your posted, your `odd` is defined as `class = c("data.table","data.frame")`. You can recopy the code in your initial post for odd into your console.

Comment: Hi, could you please check the new data in the question. I am not sure what happened. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Getting there. Only one quirk: The column for c("PRECIP", 2) is the repetition of c("PRECIP", 4).  Are you getting the same?

Comment: Well technically, one has more NA than the other, so they aren't exactly the same. That is an issue with your rollapply algorithm, ie `fill=`, and/or `align=`. Just change the parameters inside `rollapply(...)` to get the behavior you desire.

Comment: Hi, thanks for patiently explaining. I am not sure what change to make....I tried with a different variable as well (for 2 different lags), and the first one is getting repeated for the second lag. If I make any changes to rollapply, won't it apply to all instances? Sorry, if I am asking the wrong questions.....

Comment: It is not getting repeated. It just happens that width = 4 and 2 generates the same output (omitting NA and 0's)

Comment: Found the reason....When I am running your exact code, it displays the correct output in the console (With two columns named exactly the same "PRECIP_ROLL". But when I try to store it into a dataframe, the first replaces the second. Eg. test<- cbind(odd, .......). How can I avoid this?

Comment: I do not observe such behavior

Comment: Odd. Here is my output for console display: http://imgur.com/wUD4dPM while this is my output when I store in a dataframe: http://imgur.com/0i6BBz0

Comment: Sorry, the quirk persists. :-(

Comment: I think it is because when you simply print the result, you are allowed to have two columns with the same name, but when you actually store it in a data.frame, a `1` gets appended. I don't see a major problem with this behavior.

Comment: Hi, could you please check the imgur figures I gave earlier. The 1 append is not a problem for me. But along with appending in the name, the first column is repeated in the second column. Any ideas of how I can dynamically change the name of the column *before* doing the cbind? I think that will fix it.